# can we add border around title in css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, border

[border around title, with upside open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyGyi.jpg)

How can I do this type of border around heading using CSS

I tried this in Elementor but not able to do this I have tried to give it all side border then by giving subtitle  white background I have tried to give negative margin can we try this using CSS

Comment: heyy please provide your code @krutika

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with absolute position, here is an example I came up with:

```css
.title{
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.title span{
  position: absolute;
  top: -27%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <span> We are </span> <br>
  our services
 </div>
```

Comment: yes thanks that work...position: absolute  solved the problem